# Power connectors in a modern server PSU

Tags: power-supply

I am looking to design a fairly complicated, multiple-GPU system, and I need to up my understanding of modern power connectors.

There are "8 Pin EPS +12V" Power Connectors, which seem designated for GPUs, and "6 Pin PCI Express" Power Connectors. Is there standard terminology to address these? (I will need 4 of each, but it looks like I can convert SATA power to the former, so maybe my problem boils down to 4 PCI 6 pin).

Any help getting the terminology straight would be appreciated. I expected Ars Technica or Tom's Hardware would have a tutorial on the nest of power cables coming out of PSUs, but I guess the fun of the build is in sorting out these mysteries...

Comment: (no, I am not building a mining rig :-)